# Custom Class in Zend Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I'm using Zend Framework with Propel. It's easy enough to use Propel objects as my models for things that are stored in the database, but how do I go about creating a custom model such as a shopping cart that uses propel objects?

I'm thinking of creating a class called CartItem and Cart. If CartItem contains a propel Product class, and Cart contains an array of CartItems, this seems very expensive to store in a session. Normally I'd just use an array, but I'm trying to get better with OOP

Comment: Nothing wrong with storing cart data in the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297576/storing-shopping-cart-in-session

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP's Interface Serializable: http://php.net/manual/de/class.serializable.php

You can use it to convert an instance of your cart into a more efficient value (you define, what exactly is stored), which is in your case a two-dimensional array.

Try something like this:

```
<?php

class Cart implements Serializable {

    // your normal code for the Cart class

    public function serialize() {
        $cartData = array();
        foreach($this->cartItems as $item) {
            $cartData[] = array(
                'count' => $item->getCount(),
                'productId' => $item->getId()
            );
        }
        return serialize($cartData);
    }

    public function unserialize($cartData) {
        $this->cartItem = array();
        foreach($cartData as $item) {
            // replace this with the appropriate propel code
            $product = loadProductWithPropelById($item['id']);
            $this->cartItems[] = new CartItem($item['count'], $product);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Then use serialize to store the cart in the session and retrieve it:

```
<?php

// Store cart to session
$_SESSION['cart'] = serialize($cart);

// get cart from session
$cart = unserialize($_SESSION['cart']);

?>
```

Good Luck with your Project!